# Speed up loading emacs by compiling packages

Tags: emacs, elisp

With packages loading such as orgmode, nxhtml, yasnippet, I see that the loading of emacs slowed down pretty much.

I expect I can speed it up with the compilation of the packages.

- I can I do that with emacs?
- Normally, how much speed up can I expect?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make Emacs start-up faster?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778716/how-can-i-make-emacs-start-up-faster)

Comment: I'd suggest to first profile your emacs startup file; see http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ProfileDotEmacs for details. Then take a look at those packages which take the most time; if those are already compiled, make use of autoloads, eval-after-load, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can do it: M-x byte-compile-file on each .el that you want to compile.  It won't speed things up as much, though, as will using "autoload" and "eval-when-require".

Comment: Ditto what he said.  Also, if you're using a package that came with emacs, then it is probably already byte-compiled.

Comment: The question is about packages not individual files, so IMHO M-x byte-recompile-directory might be a better fit.

Answer (score 5):

Generally everything that comes with the Emacs installation is byte compiled and every package you installed via a Linux distribution package management system is compiled as well. If you're using [ELPA](http://tromey.com/elpa/) - it byte compiles the packages after downloading them. That said, byte-compilation will not bring you any significant performance gains.

If we assume that the greatest bottleneck with Emacs performance is its startup time, you'd do a lot better to start a single **Emacs instance as a daemon**(emacs --daemon) and share it between multiple **emacsclient** processes that will start instantly once the daemon is running.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to get a speedup in your `.emacs` file doesn't have much to do with byte compilation, though you should always byte compile new packages you install.

Instead, if you know you do this in your `.emacs`:

`(require 'some-pkg)`

and then later you might do this:

`M-x command-in-pkg'

you are better off adding this to your `.emacs` file.

`(autoload 'command-in-pkg "some-pkg" "A command in some package" t)`

which will load much faster at startup than the original require.  Many packages have installation setups that have a file full of autoloads that you require in your `.emacs` file which will already be optimized as best that maintainer can get it.