# emacs: help me solve this autoload ordering problem with flymake and csharp

Tags: c#, emacs, flymake

How can I deliver a module that requires patching flymake, with minimal startup time (=autoload) and minimal impact on the user's emacs.el?

I'm working on the flymake-for-csharp module. It works with flymake, teaches it how to be more flexible with C# code files.  For example, instead of just using a makefile, flymake-for-csharp can also use a .csproj file, or can invoke csc.exe directly.

The module works fine.  I am now trying to make it autoload properly.

here's the challenge.

To define which languages get flymake'd, flymake.el includes a list of file extensions (.java, .cs, .c, etc) along with the init and cleanup routines for each of those languages.  There's an entry for C# in the default flymake.el, but as I said, the default C# behavior isn't flexible enough.  To make it more flexible, I need to replace the C# entry in the flymake alist, so that it points to the new init/cleanup logic in the flymake-for-csharp module.  Ya with me?

It's no problem patching the alist at runtime.  It looks like this:

```
  (let (elt
        (csharp-entry nil)
        (masks flymake-allowed-file-name-masks))

    ;; Find the existing C# entry
    (while (consp masks)
      (setq elt (car masks))
      (if (string= "\\.cs\\'" (car elt))
          (setq csharp-entry elt))
      (setq masks (cdr masks)))

    ;;  remove the original entry for C# ...
    (if csharp-entry
        (setq flymake-allowed-file-name-masks
              (delete csharp-entry flymake-allowed-file-name-masks)))

    ;; Now add a new entry for C#, with the custom init and cleanup methods.
    (setq flymake-allowed-file-name-masks
          (cons
           '("\\.cs\\'" flymake-for-csharp-init flymake-for-csharp-cleanup)
           flymake-allowed-file-name-masks)))
```

The long term solution is to persuade the authors of flymake and emacs to accept the logic that is currently in flymake-for-csharp. Then the alist will get the more flexible init/cleanup routines and *bob's your uncle*.

But for now I want flymake-for-csharp to work with the existing (builtin) flymake.el.  Therein lies the problem: how can I make the flymake-for-csharp autoload, while still patching the alist?

Ideally I'd like the user's emacs.el to look like this:

```
(autoload 'flymake-for-csharp-init "flymake-for-csharp" nil nil)
```

...with possibly a small `(eval-after-load ..` section.

But you see, the function `flymake-for-csharp-init` would be called only *after* the flymake alist is patched to include the new entry for C#.

Is there a way around this chicken-and-egg situation?

---

one approach I thought of was to use `(require 'flymake-for-csharp)` in lieu of `autoload`.  Within that flymake-for-csharp module, run only the patch logic, and then use autoload, somehow, for the rest of the functions.  Would this be a good idea? Would this require me to deliver flymake-for-csharp in 2 distinct files?

Another approach I thought of was to use an `eval-after-load` on flymake.el.  In that I could provide the patch function.  Couple questions with this:

- Would that work only if flymake is autoloaded?  What happens with the logic within an eval-after-load for a module that is already loaded when the (outer) eval-after-load is eval'd?
- how would I do this without impacting the user's emacs.el?

---

In summary, 
How can I deliver a module that requires patching flymake, with minimal startup time (=autoload) and minimal impact on the user's emacs.el?

Comment: No idea, but what you're doing seems awesome and I bravely applaud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, having the user add this to their `.emacs` would solve the problem:

```
;;;###autoload
(eval-after-load "flymake" '(code-that-patches-flymake-allowed-file-name-masks))
(autoload 'flymake-for-csharp-init "flymake-for-csharp" nil nil)
```

Now, if you work with the folks using your package, you can use the [loaddefs.el trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189159/emacs23-elisp-how-to-properly-autoload-this-library/4189794#4189794) to get this code automatically loaded by the user by putting the `;;;###autoload` comment right before the `eval-after-load` line in your package, and then rebuild the `loaddefs.el` file.

But, if you're hoping for a solution for general usage in the internets, you need the user to have both lines in their `.emacs`.

---

A comment on your cleanup code, I believe it can be simplified to:

```
(let ((csharpentry (assoc "\\.cs\\'" flymake-allowed-file-name-masks)))
  (when csharpentry
    (setcdr csharpentry '(flymake-for-csharp-init flymake-for-csharp-cleanup))))
```

Comment: hey, a followup...let's call the fn that patches the alist `flymake-for-csharp-monkeypatch-flymake`. suppose I provide that fn in `flymake-for-csharp.el`, and mark it with `;;;###autoload`. Then, would the users just need to include a single line, `(eval-after-load "flymake" '(flymake-for-csharp-monkeypatch-flymake))` in their .emacs? That would minimize impact to .emacs. It would also imply, I think, loading the entire flymake-for-csharp module when flymake is loaded, whereas your suggestion would defer loading the csharp module, but maybe that's ok. what do you think?

Comment: @Cheeso The `;;;###autoload` only works if you have something build the `loaddefs.el` file (see the link in my answer for `loaddefs.el trick`.  So, if you got the autoload to work, then I believe you are correct.