# How do I make an interactive command automatically available?

Tags: emacs

I feel like this question is super basic, but I haven't been able to figure out how to automatically make a simple interactive command available in an Emacs session...

This is in `~/random/exploration/exploration.el`.

```
;;; Code:

;;;###autoload
(defun exploration ()
  "a test package"
  (interactive)
  (message "hi"))

(provide 'exploration)
;;; exploration.el ends here
```

This is in `init.el`:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name  "~/random/exploration"))
```

`exploration` isn't available via `M-x` though. I have to do `M-: (require 'exploration)` before it appears.

How would I make this command available automatically, like plugins do? I've been poring over the docs for `load-path` and `autoload` but can't figure out how to make this happen.

I want to do this so I can put other functions in `exploration.el` and have them only available after the user first does `M-x exploration`. That implies that `exploration` needs to be autoloaded.

Comments on any redundancies in what I've done here, or tips on how I could have debugged this on my own would also be welcome.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189159/emacs23-elisp-how-to-properly-autoload-this-library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `;;;###autloload` comment is just a comment. When Emacs is built (or a suitably intelligent package manager installs your code as a package) it generates an actual autoload, but outside of that, you need to do it yourself.

```
(autoload 'exploration "exploration" nil t)
```

Specify an explicit path in the second parameter and you won't actually need the `load-path` manipulation to accomplish what you describe.

See also https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Autoload.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to either load the file instead of adding it to the `load-path` or you need to put `(require 'exploration)` to your `init.el` file after adding the folder to the `load-path`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `autoload` function:

```
(autoload 'exploration "exploration")
```

If you don't modify `load-path`, you need an absolute path as the second argument.

Alternatively, install your script as a package, either through MELPA (assuming you can get it there), or locally with `package-install-file`.  This will take care about autoloads for you.