# How to make my customized emacs load faster?

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs23

As I add more and more plugins and configurations to my emacs' init.el , it's startup is getting more and more slow. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make Emacs start-up faster?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778716/how-can-i-make-emacs-start-up-faster)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your `.emacs` or `init.el` shouldn't have many `require` or `load` commands, it should mostly have `autoload`. The [`autoload`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Autoload.html) function tells Emacs “if you ever need this function, load that file”. This way, the file is only loaded when and if you actually use the function. You only need `require` (or very rarely `load`) in two cases:

- if there's a customization that needs to go into effect immediately (e.g. `(require 'cl)`, a color theme);
- if what you're loading is a small file that contains the `autoloads` and other start-up definitions of a package (e.g. `(require 'tex-site)`.

If you're not doing this already, calling `autoload` for things like mode-specific customizations can cut your startup time down significantly, because Emacs will have to load fewer files.

Furthermore, make sure your files are byte-compiled; they'll load a little faster (less CPU time). Call `M-x emacs-lisp-byte-compile` on each `.el` file, or `M-x byte-recompile-directory` (these commands are in the Emacs-Lisp menu).

Finally, note that load times don't matter so much because you should be [starting Emacs at most once per session](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emacs-Server.html). Start Emacs automatically when you log in, either with a window or in the background with the `--daemon` option. Then, to edit a file, run [`emacsclient`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Invoking-emacsclient.html). You can also [tell `emacsclient` to start Emacs if it's not running yet](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/emacsclient-Options.html) if you'd rather not start it when you log in.

Comment: For people having problems with the daemon mode and the editor colors, this is very useful: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SettingFrameColorsForEmacsClient

Comment: If you don't like confirming every directory and/or file:             `(byte-recompile-directory "~/where-i-put-my-packages/" nil nil)` or change the last nil value to something non-nil to force recompilation.  `(describe-function 'byte-recompile-directory)` rocks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can [compile it](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Byte-Compilation.html#Byte-Compilation) as an .elc file (M-x byte-compile-file)

Comment: From [48.4 The Emacs Initialization File](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html#Init-File): *"Byte-compiling your init file is not recommended ...  If your init file defines many functions, consider moving them to a separate (byte-compiled) file that you load in your init file."*

Comment: ...That said, there are suggested mechanisms for automatically maintaining a byte-compiled version of your Emacs initialization file. For instance, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/779145/1497596) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/780735/1497596).