# How do I profile my emacs configuration?

Tags: emacs, profiling, dot-emacs

My emacs configuration takes a very long time to load.  How can I easily find the offending parts and optimize them?

Comment: How long is "very long" ? I never imagined emacs being something that would take long to load.

Comment: 30 seconds, even with Raid 0 SSDs  :-( :-(

Comment: Be sure to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778716/how-can-i-make-emacs-start-up-faster to see how to fix the problem.

Comment: @Trey, thanks.  I already do everything there but autoloads, which seem tedious.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Very useful package: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ProfileDotEmacs

Just skip loading your init file and let ProfileDotEmacs load/profile it for you:

```
emacs -Q -l profile-dotemacs.el -f profile-dotemacs
```

Comment: The wiki is a source of infinite wisdom for all things Emacs.

Comment: @Phob: I encourage you to click on the tick mark next to this answer, just below the up/down vote buttons. :-)

Comment: Fails with 'Wrong type argument: number-or-marker-p, nil' for me.

Comment: @Micha90 if it shows 0 seconds, it may mean that you need to define the correct .el file to run the profiler on. By default it is `~/.emacs`, but in my case I needed to change it to `~/.emacs.d/init.el`. In the file `profile-dotemacs.el` change the value of the variable named `profile-dotemacs-file`.

Answer (score 8):

Another solution is [ESUP](https://github.com/jschaf/esup), the Emacs Start Up Profiler.  It can profile your config file without leaving Emacs - it accomplishes this by starting a new Emacs as a child process, getting profile information from it.

Comment: I installed esup, did M-x esup... and that's it. IDK how it was in 2016, but in 2020 `esup`was really simple to use to me.

Comment: ^ the package requires having GUI Emacs

Answer (score 2):

By using divide and conquer, of course!

Drop the bottom half of your `.emacs`. See if the speed improves. (If so, the culprit is within the bottom half; otherwise it's in the top half.) Restore the working half. Chop off half of the broken half, and repeat the process until you have isolated the problem.

Comment: This takes O(startup_time * log(config_size)).  Startup time = 30 seconds, config_size = 20,000 lines.  This works for most people, but is really inconvenient for me.

Comment: @Phob: Yeah, 20k lines is seriously more over-the-top than I thought ever possible. ;-)

Comment: @Phob, no offense, but 20,000 lines means you're doing it wrong.

Comment: My config is DRY. I am just doing it _more_ .

Comment: That's fine if there's one thing that is causing a big slowdown. But it won't work if there are many things culminating in an overall slowdown.