# Altering what Emacs loads depending upon file being editted

Tags: emacs, nxhtml

Currently, to use a certain plugin (nxhtml), I place the following statements in my .emacs,

```
(load "<plugin-location>/autostart.el")
```

Therefore everytime I open emacs, this is loaded, regardless of whether I am editing a file that the plug-in is applicable to (e.g. .htm). This loading is undesirable as it takes several seconds, how might I alter my settings so that this plug-in is loaded only when I am editing .htm or .css files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make Emacs start-up faster?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778716/how-can-i-make-emacs-start-up-faster)

Comment: autostart.el doesn't do a huge amount of work -- it sets up autoload declarations in order to defer the real work until needed. Does it really take several seconds? Have you byte-compiled it?

Comment: @phils With and without the load statement makes about a 5-second difference at start-up. I'm not sure what byte-compiled means or how you would go about doing it.

Comment: By definition, interpreted languages do not get "compiled" in the way that a language like C does; however, many interpreted languages support "byte-compilation" meaning that the source code is compressed into a form which, while still interpreted, can be interpreted *faster* than the original source. Emacs lisp files `*.el` can be byte-compiled into equivalent `*.elc` files which Emacs will use in preference. There are standard commands for byte-compiling, however in this instance nXhtml provides its own: `M-x nxhtmlmaint-start-byte-compilation`

Comment: As documented here, btw: http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/nXhtml/doc/nxhtml.html

Comment: This fixed the problem, start-up time is barely noticeable now. Thanks

Comment: Great; I'll make it a proper answer in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nXhtml's autostart.el doesn't do a huge amount of work (it sets up autoload declarations in order to defer the real work until needed), however it can still be slow if you have not yet byte-compiled the library.

nXhtml provides its own command for handling the necessary byte-compilation (which is documented at http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/nXhtml/doc/nxhtml.html), so you can just type:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `nxhtmlmaint-start-byte-compilation` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean about plugins. For format specific code, I use hooks:

```
(add-hook 'sgml-mode-hook
      '(lambda () (setq sgml-indent-data t)
         (turn-on-auto-fill))
      )
```

Can you try loading the plugins in hooks?