# Emacs performance with huge .emacs file

Tags: emacs, elisp

I was wondering if emacs performance would suffer if one has many implemented "but unused" functions in .emacs file.
Basically, are these functions loaded in memory "unnecessarily" and wait until they are used? 
Also, is there anything one could do to improve speed and runtime of emacs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers to your questions are "yes" and "yes" - please see the SO question [how can i make emacs start up faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778716/how-can-i-make-emacs-start-up-faster).

Other than start-up time, there's really no downside to having a "huge" .emacs file, unless you've got a tiny machine.  People run Emacs for days/months, opening large numbers of files, and Emacs handles it all quite nicely.

Comment: Thanks Trey, that answers my questions.